# Find a node where all nodes that point to it have a property set to the same value

Tags: neo4j

If I were to use this query:
`MATCH (x {foo:'bar'})-->(y) RETURN y;`
it would return any nodes 'y' that have one or more nodes 'x' pointing to it with the property 'foo' set to value 'bar'. I only want to find the nodes 'y' where *every* node pointing to it has 'foo' set to 'bar'. So let's say that besides 'x', nodes 'a' and 'b' also point to 'y'. 'y' should only be returned if all three nodes 'x', 'a', and 'b' have 'foo' set to 'bar'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following data....

```
create (x:Test {name: "X", foo:"bar"})
create (a:Test {name: "A", foo:"bar"})
create (b:Test {name: "B", foo:"bar"})
create (c:Test {name: "C", foo:"notbar"})
create (y1:Test {name:"Y1"})
create (y2:Test {name:"Y2"})
create x-[:CONNECTED]->y1
create a-[:CONNECTED]->y1
create b-[:CONNECTED]->y1
create x-[:CONNECTED]->y2
create c-[:CONNECTED]->y2
```

This query returns only the y nodes with connected nodes with `foo = 'bar'`

```
match (n:Test)-->(y:Test)
where n.foo = 'bar'
with y, count(n) as num_bar
match (n:Test)-->y
with y, count(*) as num_total, num_bar
where num_bar = num_total
return y
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think you understood my question completely. If, for example, y had three nodes pointing to it, a b and c - I would only want y returned if all three nodes had 'foo' set to 'bar'.

Comment: you're right - i did not understand it but i do now. I will re-answer.

Comment: Hmmm, so does this only work when looking at two nodes like y1 and y2? I'm a bit confused. Maybe the solution is to first count all the nodes pointing to `y`, and then count only the nodes pointing to `y` that have `foo` set to `"bar"` and comparing the two numbers to see if they are equal.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to confuse you, I just wanted to show one `y` that had only `bar` nodes pointed to it and one that did not.  Yes, it would only work if there were other `y` nodes.  The counting solution is a much better idea.

Comment: I updated my previous answer with what is above but the answer @wassgren provided is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this may work for you:

```
MATCH 
    (node { foo:"bar" })-[:REL]->(target), 
    target<-[:REL]-(checkPoint)
WITH 
    target, 
    COLLECT(checkPoint) AS checkPoints
WHERE ALL (x IN checkPoints 
       WHERE x.foo="bar")
RETURN target
```

So, `target` will be a hit for all nodes where all related nodes has the property `foo="bar"` set. The query match returns **all** nodes that are connected to `target`, after that it filters out the nodes based on the `ALL`-predicate that you can read more about [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1/cypher-refcard/).

I think that it would be very good if you can find a fast starting point for `target` based on an id or index hit. Furthermore, I strongly recommend that you use `Label`s for the nodes to quickly narrow down the matching and to gain (much) better performance.

**Edit:** Updated the query after more input from the OP.

Comment: Thanks, but the node I'm looking for doesn't need `foo` set to `"bar"`, so in your example I'm actually looking for `y`, not `target`. Also, I tried this query and returning `y`, but it doesn't work correctly. For example, it is returning `y` where two of three nodes pointing to `y` have `foo` set to `"bar"` - I only want `y` when _all_ nodes pointing to `y` have `foo` set to `"bar"`. Does that make sense?